# Create episode for each value with new Begin and End Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is in reference to below Question

[Loop through each value to the seq num](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885221/loop-through-each-value-to-the-seq-num)

But now Client want to see the data differently and started a new thread for this question.
 below is the requirement.

```
This is the data .
ID  seqNum  DOS         Service End Date
1   1       1/1/2017    1/15/2017
1   2       1/16/2017   1/16/2017
1   3       1/17/2017   1/21/2017
1   4       1/22/2017   2/13/2017
1   5       2/14/2017   3/21/2017
1   6       2/16/2017   3/21/2017



Expected outPut:

ID    SeqNum      DOSBeg       DOSEnd
1      1          1/1/2017     1/30/2017
1      2          1/31/2017    3/1/2017
1      3          3/2/2017     3/31/2017

For each DOSBeg, add 29 and that is DOSEnd. then Add 1 to DOSEnd (1/31/2017) is new DOSBeg. 
Now add 29 to (1/31/2017) and that is  3/1/2017 which is DOSEnd . Repeat this untill DOSend >=Max End Date i.e 3/21/2017.
```

Basically, we need episode of 29 days for each ID.

I tried with this code and it is giving me duplicates.

```
with cte as (
      select  ID, minDate as DOSBeg,dateadd(day,29,mindate) as DOSEnd
     from #temp 
      union all
      select  ID,dateadd(day,1,DOSEnd) as DOSBeg,dateadd(day,29,dateadd(day,1,DOSEnd)) as DOSEnd 
      from cte
     )
select  ID,DOSBeg,DOSEnd
from cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

Here mindate is Minimum DOS for this ID i.e.  1/1/2017
```

I came up with below logic and this is working fine for me. Is there any better way than this ?

```
declare @table table (id int, seqNum int identity(1,1), DOS date, ServiceEndDate date)
insert into @table
values
(1,'20170101','20170115'),
(1,'20170116','20170116'),
(1,'20170117','20170121'),
(1,'20170122','20170213'),
(1,'20170214','20170321'),
(1,'20170216','20170321'),
(2,'20170101','20170103'),
(2,'20170104','20170118')

select * into #temp from @table

--drop table #data
select distinct ID, cast(min(DOS) over (partition by ID) as date) as minDate
,row_Number() over (partition by ID order by ID, DOS) as SeqNum,
DOS,
max(ServiceEndDate) over (partition by ID)as maxDate
into #data 
from #temp



--drop table #StartDateLogic
with cte as 
(select ID,mindate as startdate,maxdate
from #data
union all
select ID,dateadd(day,30,startdate) as startdate,maxdate
from cte
where maxdate >= dateadd(day,30,startdate))
select distinct ID,startdate
into #StartDateLogic
from cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

--final Result set
select ID
,ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by ID order by ID,StartDate) as SeqNum
,StartDate
,dateadd(day,29,startdate) as EndDate
from #StartDateLogic
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track wit the recursive cte, but you forgot the anchor.

```
declare @table table (id int, seqNum int identity(1,1), DOS date, ServiceEndDate date)
insert into @table
values
(1,'20170101','20170115'),
(1,'20170116','20170116'),
(1,'20170117','20170121'),
(1,'20170122','20170213'),
(1,'20170214','20170321'),
(1,'20170216','20170321'),
(2,'20170101','20170103'),
(2,'20170104','20170118')


;with dates as(
    select top 1 with ties id, seqnum, DOSBeg = DOS, DOSEnd = dateadd(day,29,DOS)
    from @table
    order by row_number() over (partition by id order by seqnum)
    union all
    select t.id, t.seqNum, DOSBeg = dateadd(day,1,d.DOSEnd), DOSEnd = dateadd(day,29,dateadd(day,1,d.DOSEnd))
    from dates d
    inner join @table t on
    d.id = t.id and t.seqNum = d.seqNum + 1
    )


select * 
from dates d
where d.DOSEnd <= (select max(dateadd(month,1,ServiceEndDate)) from @table where id = d.id)
order by id, seqNum
```

Comment: thank you very much :-).I did not understand why is it top 1 ?

Comment: so that we start with a single row to begin the recursion and avoid duplicates

Comment: When We have more ID's, it is taking off the other values.

Comment: thank you for helping me out with this, but why is Seqnum=7 for ID 2? It should be 1. Seqnum is partitioned by ID

Comment: I came up with some logic and giving me the right answer. is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: that's because i didn't statically insert the data... see the edit. The original was based off a single ID tha tyou had

Comment: Also, can you accept this answer? The code produced the expected results even after you changed the sample data...